# Opposite of .net Encoding.UTF8.GetString

Tags: c#, encoding

What is the complementary method of `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

That is, if `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` decodes bytes in a byte array into a string, what method encodes a string into bytes in a byte array, so that

```
var somestring == Encoding.UTF8.GetString(method(someString));
```

is true?

Comment: Have you searched for the obvious `GetBytes`?

Comment: It's particularly obvious if you happen to know the name of the method.  Of course that's what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 9):

The reverse method is `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. Similar classes exist with the same method for ASCII and UTF16 encodings.

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TestString")
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it

Comment: Of course, non-Unicode encodings can't satisfy `somestring == encoding.GetString(encoding.GetBytes(someString))` for all values of `somestring` because `somestring` is a sequence of characters that range over the entire Unicode character set.

Comment: Tom comment is well explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45410259/1546137