# What is the reason that Encoding.UTF8.GetString and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes are not inverse of each other?

Tags: c#, .net, utf-8

Probably I am missing something, but I do not understand why Encoding.UTF8.GetString and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes are not working as inverse transformation of each other?

In the following example the myOriginalBytes and asBytes are not equal, even their length is different. Could anyone explain what am I missing?

```
byte[] myOriginalBytes = GetRandomByteArray();
var asString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myOriginalBytes);
var asBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(asString);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

They're inverses if you start with a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, but they're not if you just start with an *arbitrary* byte sequence.

Let's take a concrete and very simple example: a single byte, 0xff. That's not the valid UTF-8 encoding for *any* text. So if you have:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0xff };
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

... you'll end up with `text` being a single character, [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm), the "Unicode replacement character" which is used to indicate that there was an error decoding the binary data. You'll end up with that replacement character for *any* invalid sequence - so you'd get the same text if you started with 0x80 for example. Clearly if multiple binary inputs are decoded to the same textual output, it can't possibly be a fully-reversible transform.

If you have arbitrary binary data, you should *not* use `Encoding` to get text from it - you should use `Convert.ToBase64String` or maybe hex. `Encoding` is for data that is naturally textual.

If you go in the opposite direction, like this:

```
string text = GetRandomText();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
string text2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

... I'd expect `text2` to be equal to `text` with the exception of odd situations where you've got invalid *text* to start with, e.g. with "half" a surrogate pair.

Comment: I revisited my old question, and I have to say that's a great answer (for an interesting question), thx again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ASCII class. I calculated a salt value ( `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(byte[])` ) and stored that byte array into a SQL table ( `varchar` ) using `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString()` method. This proved to be wrong solution although you think you are using ASCII class.( Assuming ASCII is one byte per character encoding.)

```
void WrongSolution()
{
    byte[] salt_byte = null;

    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt_byte);
    string salt_string = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(salt_byte);
    byte[] salt_byte2 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt_string);
}
```

In the above code, salt_byte  and salt_byte2 are 2 different byte arrays.
Here is the correct solution:

```
void CorrectSolution()
{
    byte[] salt_byte = null;

    new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt_byte);
    string salt_string = Convert.ToBase64String(salt_byte);
    byte[] salt_byte2 = Convert.FromBase64String(salt_string);
}
```